# MySQL workbench has encountered a p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m Parameter is not valid

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL workbench was working properly till last login(yesterday). When I tried to open an existing connection(today), this error was popped up. I was trying to convert tables from MSSQL to MySQL yesterday.

Detailed error message

> MySQL workbench has encountered a problem
> Parameter is not valid
>
> We are sorry for the inconvenience but an unexpected exception has been raised by one of the MySQL Workbench modules. In order to fix this issue we would kindly ask you to file a bug report. You can do that by pressing the [Report Bug] button below.
>
> Please make sure to include a detailed description of your actions that lead to this problem.
>
> Thanks a lot for taking the time to help us improve MySQL Workbench!
>
> The MySQL Workbench Team

Comment: not enough information.  Please describe the context (what are you doing?), what you tried (_what_ was working last time? what query?  on what data?  Was the table altered?), what failed, what the error was, whether it's reproducible (fails every time? with the same message? for everyone or just you?)

Comment: Is anymore information needed?

Comment: did this happen when you tried to connect (log in?), or when you tried to convert the table?  If on connect, contact your system administrators; they may have changed configuration settings.

Comment: It happened while connecting. Sad part is, system admin is on leave. So, no chance of him changing configuration settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about the normal login but migration in MySQL Workbench. This part uses separate logins to source and target servers. If your connection to the MS SQL server worked yesterday and you didn't change anything in MySQL Workbench then it is very likely something with your MS SQL server happened. So, someone needs to check if that server is still running properly and can be accessed from your machine.

Answer (score 18):

For future reference, I had the same problem out of the blue with Workbench on Windows 7 so I re-ran [MySQL Workbench installer](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/), selected **Repair** and everything went back to normal.

I guess some update messed up the install.

Comment: same here, i removed the workbench and reinstalled it again and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Okay listen up. Go to your downloads where you had actually downloaded workbench setup right click on it, you will find an option called "Repair", click on it, follow all steps, open your workbench, open your connection now!(Mine is Windows 10)

Note : You can do it by re-installing workbench too! But Repairing the tool is more convenient[PFA Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2CIS.jpg)

Comment: This is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35017065/5320906) existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today, what I simply did is

1. https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/
   go to this website.
2. download latest version of Workbench.
3. In wizard for MySQL go on second window
4. there you will see window called "Program maintenance"('Modify,repair, remove).
5. select 'repair' option, click next, and install new version of workbench.
6. while doing this don't uninstall any previous version of MySQL or any file, server of MySQL.